# Extract out outermost square

Tags: python, opencv

I want to extract out outermost square but it does not work as below. How can I get the only expected 2 image files?

- Input image (layer.png)

[image]

- Expected output (2 image files)

[image]
[image]

- Actual output (6 image files)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

- opencv.py

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import cv2 as cv
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

def main():
    image_file = 'images/layer.png'
    src = cv.imread(image_file, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
    height, width, channels = src.shape
    image_size = height * width
    img_gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    retval, dst = cv.threshold(img_gray, 1000, 255, cv.THRESH_TOZERO_INV)
    dst = cv.bitwise_not(dst)
    retval, dst = cv.threshold(dst, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY | cv.THRESH_OTSU)
    contours, _ = cv.findContours(
        dst, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
        area = cv.contourArea(contour)
        if area < 10:
            continue
        if image_size * 0.99 < area:
            continue
        x, y, w, h = cv.boundingRect(contour)
        cut = src[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        detector = cv.FastFeatureDetector_create()
        detector.setNonmaxSuppression(False)
        keypoints = detector.detect(cut)
        cv.imwrite('images/debug_%d.png' % i, cut)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

- To reproduce the result

```
$ git clone https://github.com/zono/ocr.git
$ cd ocr
$ git checkout 1de458a34ab14fede41bba9f6ef0d3a6356c8668
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker exec -it ocr /bin/bash
$ python3 opencv.py
```

Comment: See [Retrieval Modes](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga819779b9857cc2f8601e6526a3a5bc71): Use `cv.RETR_EXTERNAL` instead of `cv.RETR_TREE`.

Comment: @HansHirse It worked! Please post your comment as an answer. I will accept it. Thank you!   (I was trying to calculate the points...)

Comment: Feel free to self-answer your question with the updated code segment and a short explanation! :-)

Comment: @HansHirse Will do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@HansHirse gave me the answer. Thanks!

> Use cv.RETR_EXTERNAL instead of cv.RETR_TREE

- Before

```
contours, _ = cv.findContours(
        dst, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

- After

```
contours, _ = cv.findContours(
        dst, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```